# How to release log from celery task

Tags: django, logging, celery

I have a celery task that is calling a django management command using `call_command` and that management command uses the python logging framework to create a `TimedRotatingFileHandler`.

On a windows test station, I am getting the following stack trace which seems to show that the celery tasks are still holding the log file handle open after they have completed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 77, in emit
    self.doRollover()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 350, in doRollover
    os.rename(self.baseFilename, dfn)
  WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
  Logged from file myCommand.py, line XX
```

Is this a known issue and if so is there a method for getting around it?  (I have tried googling but could not find anything relevant).